# Middleware: using model in process_request and modifying it in process_response

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.6, django-middleware

Does Django flattening response after process_response?

I have this model (simplified version):

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    remains = models.IntegerField(default = 2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.is_active)
```

and middleware (simplified):

```
class TicketMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        # ...
        try:
            request.ticket = Ticket.objects.get(uuid_exact=request.GET['ticket'], is_active=True)
            print '%s %d' % (request.ticket.is_active, request.ticket.remains)
            # first case:
            return HttpResponse(request.ticket)
            # second case:
            #return HttpResponse(request.ticket.is_active)
        except Ticket.DoesNotExists:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.ticket is not None and request.ticket.remains > 0:
            request.ticket.remains -= 1
            if request.ticket.remains == 0:
                request.ticket.is_active = False
            request.ticket.save()
        return response
```

In first case I got forbidden page on fourth request:

```
   RESPONSE     PRINT
1: True         True 2
2: False        True 1
3: False        True 1
4: Forbidden
```

In second case I got forbidden page on third request:

```
   RESPONSE     PRINT
1: True         True 2
2: True         True 1
3: Forbidden
```

And this second case is the way I want. Why I must stringify my model first for properly flow? What I misunderstood?

```
django.VERSION = (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

---

### EDIT

I found the problem. In real code I use foreign key for django.contrib.auth.models.User and unicoding my Ticket model with username of associated User:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        # this works as expected
        return u'%s' % (self.is_active)
        # with this I have unexpected third step in first case
        # but I dont understand why
        #return u'%s %s' % (self.user.username, self.is_active)
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `request.ticket -= 1` and not `request.ticket.remains -= 1`. Same for `if request.ticket == 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really doubt that the first case displays two times `False`. I've made a simple test with your code, and it displays for the first case:

```
1: True
2: False
3: Forbidden
```

which is the expected behavior. As long as the `process_response` modifies the `is_active` data and saves the ticket on the second call, I don't see how a third call can return False... Unless the ticket.remains is modified somehow. With the code shown here, I can't see how it is possible that `process_response` to save the ticket with `is_active=False`, and on subsequent request `process_request` not to redirect to `Forbidden`... Which Django version do you use? Print also `ticket.remains` in the `__unicode__()` to see how it changes ...

The reason that you get `False` in the second call with 1st case is that you pass a model instance

```
return HttpResponse(request.ticket)
```

The `ticket.__unicode__()` is being called after the `process_response` is being called, during the final writing of the contents of `HttpResponse()` to the client. And since in the first scenario `ticket.is_active` is being modified in `process_response`, when  `ticket.__unicode__()` is finally called, it gets the modified value of `ticket.is_active` which is `False`.

In the second scenario the `__unicode__` is called explicitly in process_request and evaluated to 'True'.

Comment: I change some details in code samples publicied in my question regards to reality, but there still fourth-request-forbidden behaviour in first case. Thanks to you I know now that `ticket` is stringified as last after response processing, but I dont understand what is doing on third request in first case. Help.

Comment: Where do you get the response? Do you log somewhere? Or load with a browser and get the response there? My only guess is that the middleware's method `process_response` is called twice for some reason(absolutely possible). But not sure why... I mean that it doesn't make sense to return twice `False 1` to browser - it simply means that `process_response` is not called at all. But why. ..

Comment: I have only one view never called, because my middleware always return some `HttpResponse` (for test purposes only). `print` are logged with apache. There is nothing special. I'm avoid using `user.username` in ticket's model `__unicode__` method and it works, but I dont know why this have meaning.

Comment: Ahaa... here it is: `https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py`  `https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.2.x/django/core/handlers/base.py`. It seems that there is a big difference in the way 1.2 and 1.4 process the middleware's `process_response`. In 1.4 everything works fine. But it seems for some reason the process_response is not called for the second page load in your case, and it doesn't decrement the `remains` value...

Comment: Great research, thanks. I must think about upgrade my server.